# htaccess rewrite adds "index.php" when I add a trailing slash to an address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got my htaccess rewriting on the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]*)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$ /index.php?a=$1
```

that works wonderfully when i go to "mydomain.com/nameofpage"

but when i add a trailing slash "mydomain.com/nameofpage/" the browser adds "index.php" to the end and 404's me.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

**EDIT.
Figured it out**.

looks like my use of the * in the first two rewrites was trumping my final rule... long story short, here is the code that works correctly (changed * to + in three places):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]+)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$ /index.php?a=$1
```

Comment: just add `/?` before `$`

Comment: just tried that and no change

Comment: **Figured it out**, but i don't have enough reputation to post my own answer... here it is:

Figured it out... looks like my use of the * in the first two rewrites was trumping my final rule... long story short, here is the code that works correctly (changed * to + in three places):

    `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]+)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$ /index.php?a=$1`

Comment: I edited your post, to add your solution. +1 for solving it yourself. And welcome to SO.

Comment: Yes, later rewrites can trump or otherwise interact with earlier ones. You can use the flag `[L]` to cause that rewrite to be the last one in the chain.

Comment: @user1118481 I've just upvoted you, which should give you another 5 rept, but you should be able to post an answer as soon as you got over the "new user" 10 rept threshold. Now you should be able to, you should post this as an answer, so we can upvote you -- then you'll get more rept again  ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - looks like my use of the * in the first two rewrites was trumping my final rule... long story short, here is the code that works correctly (changed * to + in three places):

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/([0-9]+)$ /content.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)$ /index.php?a=$1`